# Entity Framework stopped working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a project that has been working fine for a long time. When I tried to debug the project today it said it couldn't find the Entity Framework. I thought this was weird so I tried installing the latest version of the Entity Framework. Now when it loads I get following error, which I never had before:

Invalid object name 'dbo.Events'.

There is no table in the database called events. This occurs when it hits following code:

```
myModel mmContext = new myModel();
DateTime compareDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);
List<Event> evs = mmContext.Events.Where(e => e.ListId == 1 && e.endDate >= compareDate).OrderBy(e => e.startDate).ToList();
```

Which should use the following model:

```
public class myModel : DbContext
{
    public myModel()
        : base("myConnection")
    { }

    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
}

[Table("EventCatalog_Events")]
public class Event
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    etc...
}
```

I'm at a loss as to why it's started doing this or how to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: Invalid object name 'dbo.Events'.
There is no table in the database called events.   But you are mapping db table "EventCatalog_Events" to "Event". Isn't it??

Comment: Yes it's meant to be mapping to EventCatalog_Events but this mapping appears to have stopped working. Visual Studio doesn't report any errors.

Comment: This appears to be affecting all my projects. Trying not to panic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get projects working again by doing a repair on Visual Studio. Still not sure what exactly caused the problem.

**UPDATE**
Turns out the problem was Entity Framework 6. Apparently it no longer supports the [Table("table_name")] Data Annotation due to being purely code first. Once I rolled back to Entity Framework 5.0.0 it started working again.